# An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call. GWT

Tags: gwt

We have a controller for GWT.

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("xcontroller")
public interface MobileController extends RemoteService {
    WaterUtilityUserDataset getWaterUtilityUserDataset(String p_SearchText,
        int p_PageSize, int p_CurrentPage);
}
```

And an interface `MobileControllerAsync` which redeclares the methods in `MobileController`.

```
public interface MobileControllerAsync {
    void getWaterUtilityUserDataset(String p_SearchText, int p_PageSize,
        int p_CurrentPage, AsyncCallback<WaterUtilityUserDataset> callback);
}
```

`MobileControllerImpl` implements `MobileController`.

```
public class MobileControllerImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    MobileController {
    @Override
    public WaterUtilityUserDataset getWaterUtilityUserDataset(String p_SearchText,
        int p_PageSize, int p_CurrentPage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return AppSwitch.getWaterUtilityUserDataset(p_SearchText, p_PageSize,
            p_CurrentPage);
    }
}
```

A `MobileControllerMgr` exists to convert async calls to sync ones.

```
public class MobileControllerMgr {
    private static final MobileControllerAsync controller = GWT
        .create(MobileController.class);
    public static void getWaterUtilityUserDataset(String l_searchText,
        int m_ResultSize, int currentpage,
        AsyncCallback<WaterUtilityUserDataset> callback) {
            controller.getWaterUtilityUserDataset(l_searchText, m_ResultSize,
            currentpage, callback);
    }
```

Client code calls this method of the `MobileControllerMgr`.

```
    MobileControllerMgr.getWaterUtilityUserDataset(
            l_searchText,
            m_ResultSize,
            1,
            getcallbackWaterUtilityUserList(p_uiList, p_uiListScroll,
                    p_uiPaginate, p_uiWait)
    );
```

The callback reports an error. The following is retrieved from the logs:

```
Starting Jetty on port 8888
   [WARN] xcontroller: An IncompatibleRemoteServiceException was thrown while processing this call.
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on your browser. ( Could not locate requested method 'getWaterUtilityUserDataset(java.lang.String, int, int)' in interface 'com.nirvasoft.rpmini.client.controller.mobilebanking.MobileController' )
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.decodeRequest(RPC.java:319)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:206)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:362)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
```

What might be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The exception you see explains what is wrong:

> This application is out of date, please click the refresh button on
>   your browser.

This happens when the code in your browser is from a different version that the code on your server.